# Android gradle disable removing resources without default value

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Since upgrading to Android Gradle Plugin 3.2, resources without required default values are removed. Causing the build to fail.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  warn: removing resource my.package.name:string/my_string_resource without required default value.
  /path/to/layout.xml: AAPT: error: resource string/my_string_resource (aka my.package.name:string/my_string_resource) not found
```

Can this be disabled? I'm currently using the latest Android Gradle Plugin: 3.4.0

We need that because our customer's translation process requires us to deliver test-builds of the app in another language than the default language. Default values have to be omitted so that translators can easily see what still needs to be translated.

Comment: Created a Google issue, let's see what happens: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122421108

Comment: Did you try doing a clean build ?

Comment: Yes, I running gradle clean processDebugResources fails with the above mentioned exception, when the string is not contained in the default language.

Comment: Do you've different values defined for the the `my_string_resource` ? If not or for your specific purpose if you don't want other translations, can you try using `tools:ignore="ExtraTranslation"` attribute in your String declaration and then try running the build.

Comment: Unfortunately `tools:ignore="ExtraTranslation` won't help because thats only for the Lint check. It doesn't get to that if you don't translate a certain string in the default language and use it in a layout file for instance. Because the build step: `processDebugResources` removes it, resulting in a failed build.

Comment: The issue I have created for this problem has been closed with "wont-fix" https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122421108 ... since I no longer work on the project I had the issue on nor do I currently do Android native development, I don't have the time and energy to follow this up. Since others seem to have similar problems I would suggest somebody else take this up with the Android Gradle Plugin team.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the reason for this error but in my case was because I had this wrong xml value in one of my layouts

```
android:foreground="null"
```

Exist the posibility that you had a wrong xml value

Answer (score 1):

It happens when localizing a string resource and it is missing in the default English resources.
The "required default value" just needs to be created in file `src/main/res/values/strings.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will resolve your problem. But for me, after upgrading the Android Studio from 3.2 to 3.3, I got several warnings saying that

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  warn: removing resource com.myproject:string/menu_item_copy 
without required default value.
```

For this I've changed the

```
compileSdkVersion 28
```

on app level build.gradle. After updating compiledSdkVersion those warning errors got disappeared. Try this if this works for you.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot confirm this works. Just upgraded to SdkVersion 28, and com.android.tools.build:gradle version 3.3.0. Still the same. During the gradle task: processDebugResources I see the same warning message.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with similar problem few weeks ago after we've bump our build tools version to 28.0.3. And we also have some limitations which don't allow put strings in default values folder.

So, after week of struggling with this problem and googling, I wrote the gradle script for generating missing resources. This script generates only strings, styles, integers etc (everything from "values" folders). Feel free to open PR for generating other resource types :)

https://github.com/gerra/MissingResources

Everything you need is in `missing_res_generator.gradle` file.

Comment: To use this in a project, would I be correct in assuming you add the missing_res_generator.gradle file to your root project directory and then add the line "apply from: "$rootDir/missing_res_generator.gradle" to your project's build.gradle?

Comment: @MacD yes you're right. And add `generatedMissingRes/` to you .gitignore file. But this script generate all non-default resources. If you need only the strings you need to change the filter (`it.listFiles(XML_FILES_FILE_FILTER)`).

Comment: Thanks for the extra info! And for the script in the first place :)